# Trying to get IP address from Nodejs to display in browser using AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ip-address

I forgot I had asked this question, the **ANSWER** is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944036/using-nodejs-express-and-angularjs-to-display-ip-in-the-browser/42028041#42028041)

I'm trying to use an AngularJS controller to display an IP address from Nodejs, I can't quite seem to get the $http part of the controller right... what am I doing wrong ?

```
var requestIp = require('request-ip');
// to convert the ip into geolocation coords
var geoip2 = require('geoip2');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

// set view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// public folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

geoip2.init(); // init the db

// you can override which attirbute the ip will be set on by
// passing in an options object with an attributeName
app.use(requestIp.mw({ attributeName : 'myCustomAttributeName' }));

// respond to one req
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    // http://sahatyalkabov.com/jsrecipes/#!/backend/get-users-location-from-ip-address
    //res.send('Your IP Address: ' + req.ip);
    //next();
    var ip = req.myCustomAttributeName;// use this for live
    //var ip = '207.97.227.239';/* use this for testing */
    console.log('requestIP is ' + ip);
    //res.end('Hi, your IP address is ' + ip + '\n');
    //res.render('index');
    next();

    // geolocation
    geoip2.lookupSimple(ip, function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error: %s", error);
      }
      else if (result) {
        console.log(result);
      }
    });

    res.render('index');

});

//custom
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('user location app is running');
});
```

So that is my Nodejs app. Its using 2 Node mods, request-ip and geoip2 to request the IP address and then lookup geolocation data for it.

Here is my AngularJS code

```
angular.module('UserLocation', []);

angular.module('UserLocation')
    .controller('MainController', MainController);

    MainController.$inject = ['$http'];

/*function ctrlFunc () {
    this.message = 'Hello World again';

};*/

    function MainController($http) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.result = {
            city: null
        };

        vm.message = 'Hello World';
        vm.message1 = 'Hello World again';
        // user location
        //function getLocation () {
        vm.getLocation = function() {
            return $http.get('localhost:8000', {
          //return coreService.getLocation(city, {
            params: {city: city}
          })
          .then(function(result){
            var city = result.city;
            return vm.result.city = result.map(function(item) {
              return item.city.result;
            })
          }); 
        };
    };
```

And this is a console.log of the geolocation data, that I'm trying to get to display in the browser (just city, for now)

```
    { country: 'US',
  continent: 'NA',
  postal: '78218',
  city: 'San Antonio',
  location: 
   { accuracy_radius: 1000,
     latitude: 29.4889,
     longitude: -98.3987,
     metro_code: 641,
     time_zone: 'America/Chicago' },
  subdivision: 'TX' }
```

Where am I going wrong with the `GET` request in the $http for Angular? IF that is where I am going wrong... still new with Node so I'm not sure...

**UPDATE 1**
Here is the HTML file that I'm serving via [EJS](http://ejs.co)

```
    <html ng-app="UserLocation">
<title>The MEAN Stack</title>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    {{ vm.message }}
    <br>
    {{ vm.message1 }}
    <br>
    {{ vm.result.city }}
    <script src="/assets/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have quite a mess. Does the nodejs script also serve a HTML file or is it completely separated from your angular stuff?

Comment: you're sending `index` page to the browser and looking for `json` data on `.then()`?

Comment: @yBrodsky sorry got pulled away right after I posted the question... please look at UPDATE 1 above

Comment: @Sridhar Yes, index is an EJS file and I think that is where I'm going wrong. EJS is js on the server side, isn't it?

Comment: You need to have two functions in your backend. The index where you serve the html file and another function that returns the IP. Otherwise it makes no sense that you are trying to get the IP with $http from the angular controller

Comment: @yBrodsky Yes, I now have have 2 functions on my app.js for Nodejs. 1 for serving a static HTML file client side and the other does get the IP.  I want to show the IP address on the HTML file and I was told to use $http in Angular for that.

Comment: The code you posted has only one function.

Comment: @yBrodsky yea those are old now, I'm working on restructuring this and cleaning it up. I will edit the question when done.

Comment: the ANSWER http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944036/using-nodejs-express-and-angularjs-to-display-ip-in-the-browser/42028041#42028041